# URL Rewriting in struts2

Tags: url-rewriting, struts2

In my site I am showing games in one jsp page. I am passing game id from one jsp

```
   <a href="playgame?id=<s:property value="id"/>">
```

after fetching game from action it is showing following url in address bar

```
mysite.com/playgame?id=tskaqnrg9p
```

I want to display url with game name as follows

```
mysite.com/playgame/gamename
```

How to do it

I am using struts2 framework

Comment: Take a look at the Rest plugin.  It supports pretty URLs.  Really great plugin.  http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST plugin as mentioned, or use a pattern-matching action mapper:

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/wildcard-mappings.html#WildcardMappings-AdvancedWildcards

(Or the NamedVariablePatternMatcher.)